# How to check specific place or places are contain in current viewport in google map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make makers in google map if the places I want to mark are containing in current map area. Please take a look my explanation.
I've lat and log array like,

```
var locations = [
    {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
    {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
    {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
    {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834}
]
```

When the user is looking around the map and if he reach a place where lat and lng are contained in above array, I want to show the makers for that places.

I don't know how to make it. Can you please explain me?
I'm using google map javascript api.

Answer (score 3):

```
var locations = [
    {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
    {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
    {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
    {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834}
]
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {})
var current_view_port = map.getBounds()
locations.forEach(function(item){
 if(current_view_port.contains(item)){ //returns true if in view-port
     //create a marker here 
 }
})
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds